# Why do "medicine" and "law" take "to practice" as a governing verb but "sports" do not?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, idiomatic-language

In English, there's a joke: "Why do lawyers and doctors 'practice' medicine and law? Do you feel safe knowing that your life or fate is in the hands of some who's only practicing"?

It's a good point. Why do medicine and law take "practice" as a governing verb but sports (which literally does involve practice) do not?

Comment: Probably because the verb 'practice' is being used with the meaning 'to do work of a particular type for which a lot of training is necessary'. The 'particular types' include law, medicine, pharmacy, etc, which are 'professions'. You seem, in your question, to be confusing more than one meaning of 'practice', which is why the joke is 'funny' but not does not have a 'good point'.

Comment: You can be a practising lawyer, a practising Christian, and a practising homosexual.....(sometimes all three at once)

Comment: And of course you can practice sports, it just means something slightly different.

Comment: @StuartF What does it mean to "practice sports"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's purely idiom, and has no deeper meaning.  The first meaning of "practise" was related to "practical" and meant that you actually did something (rather than passively thinking it)  Hence a "practising Christian" is one that actually goes to church.

Later it meant to follow a profession, hence a practising doctor or lawyer is one that actually heals or advocates, rather than just having a degree.

And finally, it took the sense of repeatedly do something with the intention of acquiring a skill. Hence "practise playing tennis",that is to improve your tennis by going on the court and playing, rather than just reading about the theory.

That was the sense development.  The idea of practice in the sense of doing something to learn how to do it better is the most recent sense.  There's not much point in wondering why the sense developed like this, it just *is*.

Comment: I was made to learn 'Oh what a tangled web we weave/When first we practice to deceive' as a child.